# Plugin project :apple_maps_flutter not found. Please update settings.gradle

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, apple-maps

i tried to run this app on my android device but this message appears while debugging. [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWRla.png)

Comment: Where did you got the project, if it's yours, did it run before?